# Can multiple inequality symbols be used in an inequality?

Tags: inequality

About these "inequalities" (I don't know if I'm being sarcastic): $$1 \lt 4 \gt 3$$$$6 \lt 8 \lt 15 \gt -1$$$$(6\cdot9)\gt(5\cdot10)\gt(2\cdot7)\lt(3\cdot5)\gt(-1\cdot3)$$ can multiple inequality symbols be used, like I just showed you above?  Also, the third inequality evaluates to $$54\gt50\gt14\lt15\gt-3$$ in case you don't know your times tables.  Also, they make sense as you can see.  Remember that the "alligator" (the opening of an inequality sign) "eats" (looks at) the bigger number.  I just want to know whether multiple symbols can be *used* in any kind of inequality.  Answer away!

Comment: I don't see why not, but usually that is not very useful, as, for example, we don't know anything about the relation of $1$ and $3$ in the expression $1<4>3$.

Comment: I'd like to thank Michael Hardy for replacing my asterisks with dots, which are the same parts of multiplication.

Comment: I don't detect any sarcasm there.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that.

Comment: What does he/she mean that he/she doesn't detect any sarcasm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more correct to call such a thing "a chain of inequalities" rather than "an inequality".  What's very common is cases where the inequality signs are all in the same direction, e.g. $a < b \le c < d$, because this gives you information about the relation between any two terms in the chain.  Cases where the inequality signs are in different directions, such as $a < b > c$, are less common, but I don't see anything intrinsically wrong with them.

Comment: I knew I was being sarcastic about saying "inequalities" in the beginning of my question!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but most often they all point the same way when we do it like that, because that's when they are most well-behaved. What I mean by that is that if we write $$1<2<3<6$$then just by how the $<$ symbol works, we can conclude that $1<6$.

This isn't very useful when you have concrete numbers (you already knew that this was true), but once more complicated expressions are involved, it can be quite a lot easier to prove the the inequalities $1<2$, $2<3$ and $3<6$ than to prove $1<6$ directly.

Comment: Well, they _do_ go together.